# Setting Up SSL Certificate for Single Subdomain

Tags: apache, ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-12.04

I am working on a project where I need SSL Certificate installed on a server for HTTPS protocol. I have main domain example.com and subdomain sub.example.com. Main domain is hosted on provider1, a subdomain is hosted on provider2. When accessing subdomain name, provider1 redirects to provider2 where subdomain is hosted. On that subdomain (sub.example.com) I need to setup SSL Certificate.

I managed to install certificate on a subdomain with instructions([RapidSSL](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO6252)) from provider, but HTTPS is not working.
In instructions there is IP address required for `<VirtualHost [IP ADDRESS]:443>` section.

Which IP address must be provided?

In similar solutions there is `<VirtualHost *:443>` tag with no specific IP address.
Also httpd.conf on my server is empty.